# Word meaning "without my asking"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrases

There is a specific word meaning 'without my asking' and I cannot seem to recall it whatsoever. Used in a sentence: "she told me all about her personal life 'without my asking."

Answer (score 12):

[spontaneous](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/spontaneous): Happening or arising without apparent external cause; self-generated; coming or resulting from a natural *impulse* or tendency; without effort or premeditation.

[unsolicited](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unsolicited): Not looked for or requested; *unsought*.

[unprompted](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unprompted): proceeding from natural feeling or *impulse* without external stimulus.

*unasked*: not asked for; *unrequested*: not asked for.

Comment: 'Unsolicited' certainly works fine, with rephrasing. 'Unsolicitedly' probably exists but perhaps shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative would be [unbidden](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unbidden).

Answer (score 1):

> **unsolicited** : given or supplied without being requested or asked for

This is exactly the word you're looking for.

This adjective is used fairly often with nouns like *advice* and *information*.

Comment: Yes, this is perhaps 'the correct answer'. But it's already been given.

Answer (score 1):

[Voluntarily](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/voluntarily) could be useful in some contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [proffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Proffer&oldid=342977869), where the context is one of bargaining:

> Also; as in business, a proffer can be a sign of "good faith" a first offer or proposal, to show a willingness to "barter":
>   [see good faith barganing], [barter].
>
> ---
>
> — Excerpt from the Wikipedia article for [Proffer](http://archive.is/LgWmA), which is licensed under the [CC-BY-SA 3.0.](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) terms.

Comment: But doesn't match OP's example.

Answer (score 0):

[**on one's own initiative/account**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/on+own+initiative)

> on one's own initiative/account: without prompting or directions from others; on one's own

[**on one's own hook**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+own+hook)

> on one's own hook: *US* if you do something on your own hook, you do it without anyone else telling you or asking you to do it

[**off one's own bat**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/off+own+bat)

> off one's own bat: if you do something off your own bat, you do it without anyone else telling you or asking you to do it

[**flat out**](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=%22personal+life+flat+out%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=pt&client=safari#hl=pt&q=flat+out+definition)

> flat out: in a direct manner; bluntly: told me the truth flat out

[**bluntly**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bluntly)

> blunt: abrupt and often disconcertingly frank in speech

[**abruptly**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/abruptly)

> abrupt: sudden; unexpected

[**out of the blue**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/out%20of%20the%20blue)

> out of the blue: suddenly and unexpectedly

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for the words "slamming" and/or "cramming." This is when, typically with phone subscriptions, the provider adds on services or charges that you have not agreed to.

Comment: It'd help you expanded your answe by defining the terms, citing source and relating to the answer.

Comment: Are you sure this answer responds to the question?  It seems to be about two people talking to each other, not about a third party.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard "gratuitous" used in this sense.

"The conversation detailing her personal life was both gratuitous and in poor taste."

Answer (score -1):

What do you think about [deliberately](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/deliberately) ?